# Need a proper approach for the javascript and wrapping c++ in java. so that java and javascript can communicate

Tags: java, javascript, c++, java-native-interface

I have an application in C++, which fetches list of users and displays them (offline/online status). Now i want to create a widget such that my module is used across all applications. Thus i am creating a widget in javascript.

Now, whenever this new widget is loaded/called, it will call `getContactList()` method from my application in C++.
For that i am plannig to use JNI and wrap my C++ class. (correct me if my implementation is wrong).

Need help, to know how can we make javascript call methods in java which inturn calls methods of C++.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: HTTP requests to Java listening on an appropriate port? But you can do the same in C++ so I don't see why Java is needed.

Comment: @DJV if i don't use java (JNI) how wud i pass data to/from widget to/from application.

Comment: Is this on Windows? Have you considered turning your C++ into COM objects? If you did, then, you can interop call them from JavaScript. Vice versa, there's `IActiveScriptSite` which allows you to call JavaScript code in C++.

Comment: @Sai.kumar19 I am unable to understand your exact setting. Do you want to call C++ from JavaScript in a page loaded in your browser? If that is the case you can make a C++ server listening on a port using boost.asio, Mongoose, Arachnida and many many more. Alternatively if you want to embed JavaScript in C++ code you can use SpiderMonkey, V8, Squirrelfish and many many more. Please clarify that in your question.

Comment: @DJV yes i can make c++server listening on a port. But what i have designed is a java wrapper for c++. This java wrapper class will give list to javascript. And javascript will load that list.

Comment: @Sai.kumar19 So you need a Java server listening on a specific port? How about [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

Java Applets are Client-Side. Your plan of JNI is Server side.

You need to create a Java-Server that is between Client and JNI or you get rid of Java and implement a CGI-Module in c++ and comunicate via plain Javascript (AJAX/JSON/Whatever).